# Are there any Javascript map labeling engines available?

Tags: javascript, software-recommendations

Does anyone know of a javascript library containing functions that would allow me to generate labels for points on the map so that the labels don't overlap one another, and have optional leader lines connecting the label to the point?

I'm using Esri's javascript API, but would also be interested in finding a generic conflict detection/resolution algorithm that I could adapt.

Comment: Not so Maplex but have you seen the Geometry Service - Label in Polygon example? http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/demos/util/util_label_point.html or looking for more control on your labels?

Comment: @Mapperz  Thanks for the response.  Hadn't seen that sample. There's no mention of polygon labeling in the requirements doc, only points. Think of a mapservice with a point layer in it representing cities.  Would like to label them on the client using a Name attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you want but I've used this and it works well:

https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier